# I can't understand the output of gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I'm just trying to learn to use gdb at this point.  The program I'm using it on works perfectly fine; I'm not trying to debug it or anything; I'm just testing the functionality of gdb.  Here's the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ){
        int wordcount = 0;
        int len = strlen( argv[1] );
        for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ){
                if( isspace( argv[1][i] ) && !isspace( argv[1][i-1] ) ) 
                        wordcount++;
        }   
        if( !isspace( argv[1][len-1] ) ) wordcount++;
        if( wordcount == 0 && len > 0 ) // if all characters were non-whitespace,
                wordcount = 1;          // then there was exactly one word
        printf( "%d\n", wordcount );
        return 0;
}
```

I started gdb and ran the program, setting breakpoints at lines 7 and 9.  I used the backtrace and step commands, and I don't understand their output at all.  When I typed "backtrace full" gdb gave me this:

```
#0  _start () at ../sysdeps/i386/elf/start.S:65
No locals.
```

What exactly does this mean?  What is _start?  What is ../sysdeps/i386/elf/start.S:65?  And how can there be no locals, when clearly I have declared wordcount and len?  I have tried Google, but every tutorial I can find on gdb shows it producing completely different (more detailed) output from what I got.  When I Google the string I got, I get a bunch of results on the ARM architecture.

Comment: Make sure you compile with debug symbols — on GCC, that's the `-g` flag to each compile command.

Comment: Or even better, use `-ggdb`.

Comment: The error is at the beginning of the for-loop. If `i` is `0`, what could `i-1` be? That index is out of bounds.

Comment: Okay, the -g option seems to provide somewhat more explicit output.  Haven't tried -ggdb yet.  And yeah, I noticed the error in the program when you pointed it out, ott.  That should be fairly easy to fix.  I only wrote the program to test gdb though, so the error doesn't really matter.

Comment: @ott: True, but OP wasn't asking about code correctness. It's a subtle bug; it will trip only if the first character of the command-line argument is whitespace, and you have to work at it to make that happen. It could be triggered on purpose; not likely by accident. Could be a security issue, depending on the use case.

Comment: How did you run the program?  What did you type?  Did you set a breakpoint on `main()` (`br main`)?  That's often a good start.  The `start.S` file is probably the assembler code that ends up calling `main()`, and exiting after `main()` returns.  "No locals" means that there is no debug information in/for the current object file — not hugely surprising for `start.S`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler GDB always breaks on main by default - no need to set a point. Of course, if there is no debugging information this is no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The program I'm using it on works perfectly fine;

For some definition of works. Your program has at least 2 bugs.

> When I typed "backtrace full" gdb gave me this: ... What exactly does this mean?

It's hard to tell without knowing which commands you used *before* reaching this point. Most likely you did `next` until you returned from `main`, and thus landed in `_start` (which is the routine that calls `main`, and which is where the execution of any program usually starts).

> What is ../sysdeps/i386/elf/start.S:65?

The `_start` routine is part of GLIBC, and is defined in `sysdeps/i386/elf/start.S` source file.

> how can there be no locals, when clearly I have declared wordcount and len?

You are *not* inside `main`, so whatever locals are present in `main` is irrelevant: they are only active while `main` is executing, and it's not (either not yet, or not any longer).

Comment: "For some definitions of works.  Your program has at least 2 bugs."  I can see the bounds checking bug.  Where is the other one?

Comment: @ZenHacker `argv[1]` may be `NULL`, in which case `strlen` will crash. `argv[1]` may start with a space, in which case `argv[1][-1]` will be accessed.

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing that out.  I tend to be a somewhat sloppy programmer.

Comment: @ZenHacker : Here is someone who appears to have helped. If the answer they gave you helped solve your issue, you may wish to consider accepting it.

Comment: @ZenHacker Great. Thanks, it helps SO keep track of solved/unsolved.